# Can not login to Ubuntu 13.10 after reboot

Tags: unity, 13.10, login, lightdm

For some reason on my System76 Bonobo, after a reboot, i try to login and I get a blinking cursor in the top left for a few seconds, than right back to the login screen. It SEEMS like lightdm crashes. I did several things, most of which are outlined in google searches and include reinstalling ubuntu-desktop package, resetting unity...etc. The strange part is that I can login to the guest account just fine. However, I can NOT login to a newly created account, same result as my account. I AM able to ctrl+alt+F1 and login, than startx. This gets me to an empty desktop with no launcher...etc. I am able to get the launcher back by using the compiz-configuration-manager app and choosing "Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin", however, than I have an empty panel (no icons or date/time).

It seems like an audio issue, because when i finally am back in by doing startx and compiz reset, and goto system settings, i only see "Dummy output" as an option and have no audio. However, in the guest account it magically works (as everything does).

dmesg output:

```
    ...

[    2.766190] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.766195] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    2.766310] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    2.766313] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[    2.766315] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    2.766316] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    2.766318] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    2.766319] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    2.766321] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    2.766994] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20130102 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    2.767001] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  319.32  Wed Jun 19 15:51:20 PDT 2013
[    2.777466] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[    2.864528] SKU: Nid=0x1d sku_cfg=0x40300001
[    2.864531] SKU: port_connectivity=0x1
[    2.864532] SKU: enable_pcbeep=0x1
[    2.864533] SKU: check_sum=0x00000000
[    2.864534] SKU: customization=0x00000000
[    2.864535] SKU: external_amp=0x0
[    2.864536] SKU: platform_type=0x0
[    2.864537] SKU: swap=0x0
[    2.864538] SKU: override=0x1
[    2.864856] autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    2.864858]    speaker_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    2.864859]    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    2.864860]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    2.864861]    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[    2.864862]    inputs:
[    2.864864]      Internal Mic=0x19
[    2.864865]      Mic=0x18
[    2.864866]      Line=0x1a
[    2.864868] realtek: No valid SSID, checking pincfg 0x40300001 for NID 0x1d
[    2.864869] realtek: Enabling init ASM_ID=0x0001 CODEC_ID=10ec0892
[    2.876512] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.876515] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.876522] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    2.877504] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    2.877513] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    2.877514] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    2.878499] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input6
[    2.878974] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[    2.879090] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[    2.879172] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[    2.884525] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    2.884529] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[    2.884530] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[    2.884532] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P disabled
[    2.884534] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 BGN, REV=0xC8
[    2.884580] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    2.901667] hda_intel: Disabling MSI
[    2.901676] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[    2.901711] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling 64bit DMA
[    2.902328] acpi device:03: registered as cooling_device8
[    2.902373] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    2.902432] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input10
[    2.904975] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Enable delay in RIRB handling
[    2.952048] init: failsafe main process (702) killed by TERM signal
[    2.980131] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (761) terminated with status 1
[    2.981341] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    2.984355] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[    3.002179] type=1400 audit(1389711696.747:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=849 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=858 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.002186] type=1400 audit(1389711696.747:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=849 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=858 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.002772] type=1400 audit(1389711696.747:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=849 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=858 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.399118] r8169 0000:03:00.2 eth0: link down
[    3.399172] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    3.399380] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    3.400583] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    3.408013] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[    3.460451] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input11
[    3.460539] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
[    3.679244] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    3.686668] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[    3.741997] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    3.742169] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    3.963064] psmouse serio2: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00223/0x840300/0x122c00, board id: 1760, fw id: 1211538
[    4.000476] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input13
[    4.088299] /dev/vmmon[1043]: Module vmmon: registered with major=10 minor=165
[    4.088303] /dev/vmmon[1043]: Module vmmon: initialized
[    4.098681] Guest personality initialized and is inactive
[    4.098724] VMCI host device registered (name=vmci, major=10, minor=56)
[    4.098726] Initialized host personality
[    4.117388] NET: Registered protocol family 40
[    4.497689] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (1257) terminated with status 1
[    4.722821] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    4.722853] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    4.722867] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    4.722887] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    4.722899] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    4.722919] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    4.722932] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    4.722945] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    4.759915] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1305 (vmnet-netifup)
[    4.759920] /dev/vmnet: hub 1 does not exist, allocating memory.
[    4.759929] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 1 successfully opened
[    4.769810] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1307 (vmnet-dhcpd)
[    4.769818] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 1 successfully opened
[    4.771921] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1316 (vmnet-natd)
[    4.771925] /dev/vmnet: hub 8 does not exist, allocating memory.
[    4.771934] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
[    4.773045] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1317 (vmnet-netifup)
[    4.773050] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
[    4.782284] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1319 (vmnet-dhcpd)
[    4.782290] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
[    4.897915] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    4.897976] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    5.096877] wlan0: authenticate with 60:33:4b:e3:af:7f
[    5.104826] wlan0: send auth to 60:33:4b:e3:af:7f (try 1/3)
[    5.107329] wlan0: authenticated
[    5.109693] wlan0: associate with 60:33:4b:e3:af:7f (try 1/3)
[    5.114879] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 60:33:4b:e3:af:7f (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=3)
[    5.121450] wlan0: associated
[    5.121476] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[    5.121531] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[    5.123033] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[    5.123035] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[    5.123037] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[    5.123038] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[    5.123038] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.123039] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.123040] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.123041] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[    5.123042] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[    5.180176] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1234 (vmnet-bridge)
[    5.180185] /dev/vmnet: hub 0 does not exist, allocating memory.
[    5.180194] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 0 successfully opened
[    5.180202] bridge-wlan0: device is wireless, enabling SMAC
[    5.180203] bridge-wlan0: up
[    5.180206] bridge-wlan0: attached
[    5.209995] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[    5.380145] userif-2: sent link down event.
[    5.380147] userif-2: sent link up event.
[    5.446001] NET: Unregistered protocol family 40
[    5.629704] userif-2: sent link down event.
[    5.629707] userif-2: sent link up event.
[    6.094603] /dev/vmmon[1454]: Module vmmon: unloaded
[    6.128544] bridge-wlan0: disabling the bridge
[    6.150558] bridge-wlan0: down
[    6.150562] bridge-wlan0: detached
[    9.967149] /dev/vmmon[2870]: Module vmmon: registered with major=10 minor=165
[    9.967153] /dev/vmmon[2870]: Module vmmon: initialized
[    9.978639] Guest personality initialized and is inactive
[    9.978674] VMCI host device registered (name=vmci, major=10, minor=56)
[    9.978675] Initialized host personality
[    9.994455] NET: Registered protocol family 40
[   10.047749] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 2951 (vmnet-bridge)
[   10.047754] /dev/vmnet: hub 0 does not exist, allocating memory.
[   10.047762] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 0 successfully opened
[   10.047767] bridge-wlan0: device is wireless, enabling SMAC
[   10.047768] bridge-wlan0: up
[   10.047770] bridge-wlan0: attached
[   11.055541] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 2958 (vmnet-netifup)
[   11.055548] /dev/vmnet: hub 1 does not exist, allocating memory.
[   11.055559] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 1 successfully opened
[   11.070811] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 2960 (vmnet-dhcpd)
[   11.070821] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 1 successfully opened
[   11.073559] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 2969 (vmnet-natd)
[   11.073565] /dev/vmnet: hub 8 does not exist, allocating memory.
[   11.073576] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
[   11.074099] userif-3: sent link down event.
[   11.074101] userif-3: sent link up event.
[   11.074838] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 2970 (vmnet-netifup)
[   11.074843] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
[   11.088819] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 2972 (vmnet-dhcpd)
[   11.088829] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
[   12.110889] deprecated_sysctl_warning: 171 callbacks suppressed
[   12.110892] warning: process `vmware-hostd' used the deprecated sysctl system call with 1.1.
[   12.921259] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (3235) terminated with status 1
[   20.768249] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.768281] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.768294] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.768314] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.768327] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.768346] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.768358] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.768370] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.834699] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.834734] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   20.877996] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.154757] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.154790] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.154806] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.154827] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.154842] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.154864] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.154878] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.154893] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.220912] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.220949] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   32.263661] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.904510] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.904542] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.904555] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.904575] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.904588] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.904607] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.904619] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.904631] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.970675] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   39.970710] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   40.013403] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   55.580057] type=1400 audit(1389711749.300:68): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4264 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/driver/nvidia/params" pid=4280 comm="unity_support_t" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   55.580128] type=1400 audit(1389711749.300:69): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4264 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/driver/nvidia/params" pid=4280 comm="unity_support_t" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   55.580288] type=1400 audit(1389711749.300:70): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4264 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/driver/nvidia/params" pid=4280 comm="unity_support_t" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   55.600733] type=1400 audit(1389711749.320:71): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4264 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/driver/nvidia/params" pid=4280 comm="unity_support_t" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   55.600860] type=1400 audit(1389711749.320:72): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4264 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/driver/nvidia/params" pid=4280 comm="unity_support_t" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   55.905063] type=1400 audit(1389711749.624:73): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed mntpnt match" error=-13 parent=4264 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/run/user/118/gvfs/" pid=4442 comm="gvfsd-fuse" fstype="fuse.gvfsd-fuse" srcname="gvfsd-fuse" flags="rw, nosuid, nodev"
[   55.933170] type=1400 audit(1389711749.652:74): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4432 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/driver/nvidia/params" pid=4448 comm="gnome-session-c" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   55.933267] type=1400 audit(1389711749.652:75): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4432 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/driver/nvidia/params" pid=4448 comm="gnome-session-c" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   55.933551] type=1400 audit(1389711749.652:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4432 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/driver/nvidia/params" pid=4448 comm="gnome-session-c" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   63.498343] audit_printk_skb: 105 callbacks suppressed
[   63.498345] type=1400 audit(1389711757.216:112): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4264 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/4250/stat" pid=4375 comm="bamfdaemon" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   63.498362] type=1400 audit(1389711757.216:113): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=4264 profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" name="/proc/1288/stat" pid=4375 comm="bamfdaemon" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=118 ouid=0
[   66.149428] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.149461] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.149477] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.149525] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.149577] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.149627] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.149641] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.149665] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.215695] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.215736] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
[   66.259105] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
```

unity && compiz --replace output:

```
michael@michael-Bonobo-Extreme:~$ unity && compiz --replace
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
unity-panel-service: no process found
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
NVIDIA: API mismatch: the NVIDIA kernel module has version 319.32,
but this NVIDIA driver component has version 319.60.  Please make
sure that the kernel module and all NVIDIA driver components
have the same version.
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: commands
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: commands
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
WARN  2014-01-14 10:22:03 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Autopilot.Introspection' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-01-14 10:22:03 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Debug.Logging' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-01-14 10:22:03 xim.controller XIMController.cpp:90 IBus natively supported.
WARN  2014-01-14 10:22:03 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2014-01-14 10:22:03 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-01-14 10:22:03 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-01-14 10:22:03 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
```

Unity command hangs there and doesn't do anything. If i ctrl+c it breaks my UI and I need to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You could **check your driver for graphical card**. I met almost same problem. I have tried repairing gnome-desktop-*, /etc/fstab , unity, compiz, lightdm, gdm ...nothing works. But when I use unity in terminal, it told me something wrong with **fglrx**. No such device. **fglrx** is an library package for optimization of ATI **graphical card**. My card is very old and can't match this driver. I should not install it at all. After I run **sudo apt-get purge fglrx** in tty and reboot, the desktop run up again!

So I suggest you check the driver for your graphical card. I saw something mismatch in the log. I hope it is helpful. Good luck!